# What's the best Web server technology for a mobile application?

Tags: android, web-services, webserver

i'm building an android application, at some point the application will need to request data (and possibly send) from/to a web server.

Now, i have little experience about building a web server, i only built a restful web service once, and i'd like to know what's the best server-side technology to use in this case ?

I did some searching and i found out that some say that writing RESTful services is a good option.

is there any other server-side technology that could be well suited and designed for mobile applications ?

Also i need to know if this technology will support handling multiple requests at the same time.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to have possibility of receiving messages from server asynchronously or 'request-response' scheme will be enough?

Comment: it's not critical that each of the application user gets the data at the same time, so i guess 'request-response' is enough.

Comment: if so, REST based on regular HTTP will be quite enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use REST. It is quiete easy to use in android. I use rest with a simple HTTPPost/Get and I parse the data to json. This is very simply done by the libary gson.

SOAP is another way to do this. But this is more complicated on android side and if you say you have experience by a RESTful webservice this would be your choice. Otherwise I read that SOAP have a huge XML-Overhead. This does not matter if you use REST with json.

Comment: Thanks, would you recommend that i use php or java ?
i forgot to mention that i will be getting the data a database on the same server. so what's the best language to use here ?

Comment: I am using a java `jersey` as web server/service combined with the `JDBC` to connect to a mysql database. Also quiete simple to use. But you can use json with java and php. Here is a good tutorial for a jersey server [link]http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html On Client side you need to implement something like that to make a httpget and json parsing [link]http://hmkcode.com/android-parsing-json-data/

Answer (score 1):

REST is not really a technology, rather a principle. It depends on your implementation if it will be able to serve multiple clients.

I usually use php and output the data in JSON format. You can parse JSON data quite easily in android, and in php you can encode JSON with a single statement.

For the REST part, you should mainly look at when to use GET, POST, PUT and DELETE as HTTP method, depending on your request type. Look at [this page](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) for a reference